# Android Virtual WIFI

Tags: android, wifi, virtual

Is it possible to create a virtual WIFI device on Android Smartphones? On PC you can do that, its than possible to connect to 2 (or more) Networks at the same time because there are virtual Wifi Cards. I'am now wondering if this is possible on Android too. Does anyone no if its possible to create such a virtual device on Android?

Background is that i want to use a Smartphone as a "Bridge" between two WIFI-Hotspots, so that you are able to send Data from a Smartphone in WIFI 1 to a Smartphone in WIFI 2. Here is a link to a virtual Wifi implmentation from Microsoft http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/virtualwifi/ . While Surfing i found this and i wondered if this is possible on Smartphones (especially Android) too.

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems complicated ...
My method for connecting two or more devices to an android device is to create a Wi-Fi hotspot and then the mobile act as a router.

Comment: i thought that too, but i need the device to have a stable connection to another server